# Fixing time error

Tags: windows-7, laptop, motherboard, bios

I have a `hp dv7 series 3050` laptop.

Recently, I left it on charging on standy mode and someone unwillingly disconnected the charger and it turned off.

At the restart I noticed that the time was strange, every time when it reach 4pm, it automatically goes back to 3am, the same thing when I start it.

[image]

After brief research, I saw that it has a problem with the cellboard, responsible for maintaining the `BIOS` settings even after shutdown.

The `BIOS` model is `F.1b`.
I'd like to know a more professional take on what may be happening, and what should I do to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to replace the battery that keeps the [real-time clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) powered.

This picture is of an HP dv7 model with the bottom cover removed.
[image: Image by [Mark](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/iyqKrU4c2OT1DOUX)]
*Image by [Mark](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/iyqKrU4c2OT1DOUX)*

You can see the circular battery on the mid-right, and it looks like a standard [CR2032 lithium button battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CR2032_battery) which is available just about anywhere. You can often find it in stores because it's used in many other things like watches, which is why many people call it a watch battery.

Comment: It worked :) tks